# What is the proper use of async EventEmitters?

Tags: angular

I noticed that an EventEmitter can be configured to emit events asynchronously.

> `constructor(isAsync: boolean = false)`
>   Creates an instance of EventEmitter, which depending on isAsync, delivers events synchronously or asynchronously.

(taken from https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

When should my component deliver events asynchronously instead of using the default behavior?

Comment: you can read this article:
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3071-synchronous-vs-asynchronous-eventemitters-in-angular-2-beta-14.htm

Comment: I did and I'm still clueless

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you are using the `isAsync` option then every event emitted from `EventEmitter` gets wrapped in `setTimeout` making it async.

This is excerpt from the `EventEmitter` source code:

```
this.__isAsync ? 
  (value: any) => { setTimeout(() => generatorOrNext.next(value)); } :
  (value: any) => { generatorOrNext.next(value); };
```

What value does it add to you? Probably none. 
Zone's checks will happen before your code receives event, and then again once your event has been processed creating more work for the CPUs. Theoretically you could squeeze some custom stuff in between, but even angular team does not recommend it.

Read more on reasoning here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6311

Hope that helps

Comment: github link is dead. So what if child components calls some async method on parent?

Comment: @Toolkit  link should be fine now. there was an extra dot at the end.

Comment: Probably got something to do with change handlers. If you start messing with components in the middle of a change detection cycle you'll get errors. So hopefully this would mitigate that. (Educated guess)

Comment: **Word of caution:** If you do something in a component that would subsequently cause that same component to disappear BEFORE raising the async event then the firing of the event won't do anything. Why? Let's say you had a component that modified global state such that the same component was removed from the DOM. When you then try to raise an event nothing would happen because by the time `setTimeout` returns the component has been removed and the emitter would no longer have any subscribers! Could get race conditions too.